# How to recover deleted environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables, windows-10

In a lazy attempt to debug Visual Studio Community, I (as per recommendation from another forum) deleted all of the system's environment variables. I realized doing this was a HUGE mistake! Nothing works in the right-click menu on the start button (I have Windows 10). Can't do anything in the Settings app, can't even create new accounts or reset computer. Can't open any application that requires administrator approval, either.

Anybody know how I can restore these variables? Just the ones necessary for the OS to work, I don't care if my applications created special ones, I can un/reinstall later. As I type I get an error message after attempting to reset computer saying "The system could not find the environment option that was entered," basically confirming this is the issue.

Thank you!

Hardware:
AMD A10-6700 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 3.70 GHz
12.0 GB RAM
64-bit

Comment: Try system restore, if there is such a thing in W10.

Comment: For my luck, I copied the contents of the PATH before I lost it. OMG!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. In Windows 10 navigate to Start > Settings > Update & Security > Recovery
2. Under Advanced Startup, click Restart Now
3. Once the computer reboots into Advanced Startup, click Troubleshoot
4. Click Refresh Your PC

Windows 10 restores, keeps all files and apps but removes drivers and custom settings.

Comment: When I tried this, the options it presented were "keep files, remove apps". Not what I wanted, I backtracked.

Answer (score 53):

**Note:** This will only work if your command prompt was in open state.

I accidentally added a new PATH instead of editing it, and I lost my other path variables.

Tried following steps to recover my variables successfully on my Windows 7.

1. Open CMD (Win + R and type `cmd` without quotes)
2. Type `echo %PATH%`
3. copy the path variables
4. Go to "My Computer" properties -> "Advanced system settings" -> click on "Advanced" tab -> click on "Environment Variables" button -> Edit "PATH" variable and paste everything copied in the third step in -> Variable value: box.
5. Click OK in all the opened windows.

Comment: is this for user or system?

Comment: WINDOWS 10: It is Vice Versa for me, wrongly set the env variable as **path %echo%** and when I verify with **echo %path%** it displays %echo% only. But when I follow your 4th step all the paths available in the Path field

Comment: the echo path saved my life

Answer (score 24):

I was also facing the same issue and after searching everywhere i found the default path

C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

just copy this path and paste it to your path environment variable.

Comment: Why? What? I'm confused how this relates to the question.

Comment: Answers it perfectly by listing the important ones.

Comment: For my luck, I copied the contents of the PATH before I lost it. OMG!

Comment: Thanks, dude,
I was about to get a heart attack.
BUT this helped

Answer (score 9):

I face same issue like it, and I used "System Restore" for undo changes on path.

1. Open Start.
2. Search for Create a restore point, and click the result System Properties.
3. Click the System Restore button.

[image]

4. Click Next.

[image]

5. Select the most recent known working restore point that will help you to fix the current problem.
6. Click the Scan for affected programs button to see the applications that will be removed if they're installed after the restore point was created.
7. Click Close.
8. Click Next.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1. Open CMD
2. Type echo %PATH%
3. copy the path variables
4. click edit in environment variables (My Computer-> rightclick-> properties-> advanced properties-> environment variables)
5. paste the copied variables and ok

Comment: This may be the best solution if the command prompt was already open when the environment variables were lost. However, it is unlikely to work if you open the prompt after the fact.

Comment: For my luck, I copied the contents of the PATH before I lost it. OMG!

Answer (score 6):

ADD these Paths IN Environment variables in path

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
```

Apply and Save.

Restart your pc

Comment: Fixed my issue, Thanks

Comment: I used these paths with the ones showing when typing `echo %PATH%` and it fixed my issue. +1

Answer (score 5):

I just managed to hose my `PATH` with no open command shells. Or so I thought: It turned out I *did* have an instance of Visual Studio Code running. I opened a terminal from VS Code in the hopes that its environment had been initialized when I started it.

And it had: `echo $env:Path` gave me back the missing pieces.

This approach can be used with any already-running process that has some way of displaying environment variables. From Visual Studio, for example, do Tools->Command Line->Developer Command Prompt, then type `set` or `path` or `set path`. (There will be some VS extras tacked on to the end.)

Answer (score 1):

As I am using PowerShell going to post an extra here - might help someone else.

As long as your command shell is still opened you can recover your path - that is crucial.

In PowerShell you can run $Env:Path and that will return your Path environment variable. Copy and paste your your path.