# Restore the previous system path variable (windows)

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, path-variables

a question regarding messing with Windows Path variable.
My situation is quite specific:

- I was trying to install ffmpeg according to this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/
- The last step was setting the path variable `setx /m PATH "C:\ffmpeg\bin;%PATH%"`
- It worked, however afterwards I noticed that if I try to call python from the command prompt or the powershell if run as administrator, I started getting `'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` (although works fine if run as user), indicating that something is wrong with PATH variables.
- I looked into my variables and saw this edit.

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axjx2.png)

It seems to me that the command added the ffmpeg line to the system path and possibly overwritten the original, which is why there are issues when using command prompt as administrator. It probably should have added it to the user Path (not system Path variable)

If that is the case, is there a way to restore the previous system Path variable. Maybe I can paste it from the user Path variable?

Comment: ouch. I don't know off the hand if there is an easy restoration option, but here is what I have on my system path fyi: `C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files\dotnet\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;` You can use these windows paths for sure. If you have intel wifi, you may want to stick the last two in as well (or reinstall the driver). Good luck

Comment: Thank you, seems to have fixes the 'chcp' issue. Not sure if no other issues are to be anticipated, although everything seems to work fine now. Really weird that this tutorial can cause such ugly issues https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/ , maybe should be reported somewhere.

Comment: FYI, a shameless plug. Assuming you're planning on using it in Python, I wrote this package [ffmpeg-downloader](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpeg-downloader) and made it to work with my [`ffmpegio`](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio) with [a plugin](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio-plugin-downloader)

Comment: thanks, playing around with https://github.com/nateraw/stable-diffusion-videos, seems to have ffmpeg as a requirement

Comment: OK. It's shame it doesn't let you specify the ffmpeg path when calling the function

Comment: [Recover deleted environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015759/). You can also read previous values from system shadow copies without reboot.